# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")

Tags: php, mysql

This may be a duplicate question, however I searched internet for a while, and still couldn't find the solution.

I installed xampp on windows 7. The mysql is running on a random port. However, I can't access mysql from command line. I keep getting this error message:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061 "Unknown  error").

I enabled mysql for windows services as administrator, and opened the port that the mysql is using through windows firewall settings. But the problem is still not fixed, and I still can not see the port from http://canyouseeme.org/.

Comment: Did you check all the "related" questions to the right? ------->

Answer (score 0):

Open a command line with administrative privileges. Type the command below.

```
netstat -a -p tcp | findstr ":138"
```

Give it the port number that your sql is using instead of ":138" in the above example. Check if the output contains 0.0.0.0 as the IP or not. If it contains your local area network IP then use that IP to connect. Perhaps MySQL is not using all IPs to listen for connections.

Comment: Thanks Junaid, I checked, and it contains  0.0.0.0 as the IP. However, it indicated that the port is listening.

Comment: port listening is good. It means we are ready to accept connections. From the command line can you do 

    telnet localhost port 

and see if it works? Change the port to the one in use by MySQL and if this does not work then turn off windows firewall for a bit and try again.

Comment: Thanks Junaid, I tested telnet port in cmd (with and without firewall), it showed that the connection to the host is lost. May be I should change the port to mysql, and open it on firewall or router?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your mysql service is not running.
my solution:

1. open the run and type 'services.msc'
2. find the mysql count that you build(note:not the mysql, is the mysql count that you build yourself),then run this service.

Answer (score 0):

Find your Path that you are install xampp server on and open CMD Write that

```
"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld"
```

click Enter and Close , reopen CMd and write

```
  mysql -u root
```

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdboYKzD9HY)